# How to improve GameObject-Array causing Lag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game I always have about 500 objects that are active at the same time.

I have also a GameObject[]-Array that stores positions for the active objects. All other positions in the Array are set to null.

Here' an example:

I have a cube at position 5,5,0.
My GameObject Array then looks like: cubes[5,5,0] = cube;

The game runs fine when i set the maximum of the Array to something like [100,10,100]. But if i increase this to something like [200,10,200] it starts to lag.

Is there a way to improve the array so that i can save more positions (with still a maximum of 500 objects active at the same time!)

Code:

```
GameObject[] cubePrefab;
GameObject[,,] cubes;
bool[,,] world;
int worldX = 100;
int worldY = 5;
int worldZ = 100;

void Start()
{
    world = new bool[worldX, worldY, worldZ];
    cubes = new GameObject[worldX, worldY, worldZ];
}

void Update()
{
    for (var i = playerXMin; i < playerXMax; i++)
        for (var i2 = playerYMin; i2 < playerYMax; i2++)
            for (var i3 = playerZMin; i3 < playerZMax; i3++)
                if (world[i, i2, i3] && cubes[i, i2, i3] == null)
                    cubes[i, i2, i3] = Instantiate(cubePrefab);
}
```

At the start, about 500 random positions of world get set to true.

playerXMin = player.transform.position.x - 10;

playerXMax = player.transform.position.x + 10;

and so on.

Comment: Does the array save references to `GameObject`s?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin for those who are active in the scene, yes. The others are set to null.

Comment: So you could have 100 * 10 * 100 GameObjects?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin No, the maximum is about 500 objects in scene. But those 500 objects could be at 100 * 10 * 100 different positions.

Comment: Could you show more code please? how do you fill the array, how do you use it, when exactly does the game lag?

Comment: just added the code. it starts lagging when i move around with the player.

Comment: Why are you instantiating things every frame?

Answer (score 2):

So, based off the comments, you have a very sparse array. A 100 * 10 * 100 array can store 100000 objects in it, and if you are iterating it, you still have to go over all the other 99500 `null`s in it even if there are just 500 items actually in it.

I would recommend you using a more appropriate data type which allows for sparse allocations, for example, a [`Dictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx). Since `Dictionary`s are generic, and you are evitendtly trying to store some objects based off a 3D point (not necessarily in space, but still, 3 coordinates) you're looking for something like `Dictionary<Vector3Int, GameObject>`. I recommend [`Vector3Int`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3Int.html)  as a key since it only deals in *integers*, so you'll able to avoid all the shenanigans related to [floating points](http://floating-point.info/).

With a sparse structure, you can avoid looping through non-existent positions, which will greatly reduce the time it takes to iterate it in such an extreme case. Do note that sparse structures are usually technically slower, if you were to fill all 100000 positions. But since you aren't nearly even touching that amount, the reduction in iteration time will help you *a lot*.

Comment: @AlpakaJoe Do note that you are `Instantiate`ing things inside `Update`. `Update` runs _EVERY FRAME_, so you're creating A LOT of objects indeed, and that is likely the main culprit of the lag. You might want to only instantiate once at startup.

Comment: I'm almost sure you're trying to implement some naive "voxel" system (like Minecraft's), and let me tell from experience, instantiating a `GameObject` per cube is _not_ going to get you any acceptable level of performance. I suggest you reading more about voxel engine implementations.

Comment: i already build a voxel-based system (not this one) which is working fine, thanks ;)